# perfect hash table sub-table construction success probability

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

Question:How many times must you attempt to construct one of a perfect hash table’s sub-tables so
you have one with probability greater than 99.9999%? This is a failure rate of 1 out of million

My answer is: 4n time. But i know i am wrong.

I am novice so need help.

Comment: To get better help, use a more descriptive title, something like "perfect hash table subtable construction success probability."

Comment: @JeffLearman done. Thanks. Can you please help me now?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the right guy to answer your question.  Good luck!  Can you tell us how you derived 4n?

Comment: JeffLearman  through lecture slides